# How can I instal Docky on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: gnome-shell, mono, dock, 19.04, docky

I've been using [Docky](https://launchpad.net/docky) for almost 10 years. Yesterday I upgraded Ubuntu to 19.04 and to my surprise I realised that during the upgrade Docky got removed. I tried adding Docky PPA again, but got the message that Disco distro is not supported. I tried manually installing Docky from a .tar.gz package, but I keep getting infinite dependency errors, last one being:

> configure: error: Package requirements (gconf-sharp-2.0) were not met:
>
> No package 'gconf-sharp-2.0' found
>
> Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
>   installed software in a non-standard prefix.
>
> Alternatively, you may set the environment variables GCONF_SHARP_20_CFLAGS
>   and GCONF_SHARP_20_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
>   See the pkg-config man page for more details.

What on Earth is going on here? How do I install Docky back again?

Comment: Move to *cairo-dock* or *plank*?

Comment: @DKBose Thanks for the suggestion. I'd prefer to continue using Docky.

Comment: @DKBose actually it's been quite a long time since I tried Plank. Your comment made me try it again and I see that now Plank has the 'fish eye'/zoom effect on hovering icons. This is what I want so I guess Plank is a fair substitution for Docky. Many thanks for the suggestion! Now if only I could get the weather and separator docklets...

Comment: Thanks for this question and the comments - from how it looks like it seems to me that plank is a fork of docky...